# Codeigniter : getting Duplicate entry error ,when importing excel file in to database

Tags: codeigniter

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1062

Duplicate entry 'Company name' for key 'slug'

INSERT INTO `ph_companies` (`name`, `slug`, `about_us`, `status`, `datetime`) VALUES ('Company 01', 'Company name', 'pdc company : etc', 1, '2016-06-02 12:25:09')

Filename: core/MY_Model.php

Line Number: 61

**controller**

```
function import(){
        require_once APPPATH . 'libraries/excel_reader.php';
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $target = basename($_FILES['filepegawaiall']['name']) ;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filepegawaiall']['tmp_name'], $target);
            $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($_FILES['filepegawaiall']['name'],false);
            $baris = $data->rowcount($sheet_index=0);
            for ($i=2; $i<=$baris; $i++)
            {
                $save_data = array();
                $save_data['name'] =$data->val($i,1);
                $save_data['slug'] =$data->val($i,2);
                $save_data['about_us'] =$data->val($i,3);
                $save_data ['status'] = 1;
                $save_data['datetime'] =$this->Company_model->getCurrentDatetime();

                if(!$this->Company_model->__insert('ph_companies',$save_data)){
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Record couldn\'n inserted. Please try again.');
                }
                else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'companies  data created.');
                    //redirect('admin/company');
                }
            }

            unlink($_FILES['filepegawaiall']['name']);
        }
        $this->load->view('admin/template/header');
        $this->load->view('admin/company/import',$this->data);
        $this->load->view('admin/template/footer');
    }
```

Guide me how do i solve this..?   !! thanks !!

Comment: May be you've set `slug` column as your table's primary key.

Comment: my table structure looks   
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ph_companies` (
  `company_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `logo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `about_us` text NOT NULL,
  `slider_images` text NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `slug` (`slug`)
) ;

Comment: @Harshita you set slug as unique value. That why you have that error.

Comment: thanks, its working now.....!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ph_companies ( company_id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, category_id int(255) NOT NULL, name varchar(250) NOT NULL, slug varchar(250) NOT NULL, logo varchar(100) NOT NULL, status tinyint(4) NOT NULL, about_us text NOT NULL, slider_images text NOT NULL, datetime datetime NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (company_id)) ;
```